# Create a 3D topographic map with locations marked on the map using R

Tags: raster, r, topography, ggplot2, plotly

I am currently trying to create an interactive 3D surface plot using plotly in R. My dataset includes a matrix of Latitude and Longitude and I have a DEM for the region I would like to make this surface plot for. However, I am unable to do the same.

I have a dataframe Points.sp that contains a list of Lat/Long along with elevation data for areas where I have sampled.

```
> head(Points.sp)
                         Points     Long      Lat Elevation
1                                    NA       NA        NA
2                      Nair212       NA       NA        NA
4                      CESF543 75.72130 12.88470   876.000
5                     CESF1587 75.93559 11.93745  1494.523
6          tysoni_WILD15AMP650 75.82200 12.38000  1051.000
7           tysoni_SDBDU201274 75.65570 12.22010  1176.000
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
Points_new <- data.frame(Points.sp$Long, Points.sp$Lat, Points.sp$Elevation)
Points_new <- as.matrix(Points_new)
p <- plot_ly(z = ~Points_new) %>% add_surface()
p
```

[image]

In the above plot, I manually loaded the elevation values for each of these points, but the problem being that I need these points on a DEM for the region, and everytime I try to load the DEM, I get an error saying - 'z' must be a numeric matrix.

The DEM here is a raster for the region and I obtained it from the SRTM dataset and cropped it to contain my region only.

```
 elev <- raster("E:\\MasterThesis\\Absence Approach\\Data\\Elevation_Data\\alt\\alt")
 cr1 <- crop(elev, extent(WG.new)) #WG.new is a mask for a smaller region
 newelev<- mask(cr1, WG.new)

 > newelev
  class       : RasterLayer 
  dimensions  : 1577, 624, 984048  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
  resolution  : 0.008333334, 0.008333334  (x, y)
  extent      : 72.87501, 78.07501, 8.11667, 21.25834  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
  data source : in memory
  names       : alt 
  values      : -14, 2625  (min, max)
  attributes  :
         ID COUNT
  from: -431     2
  to  : 8233     1
```

If I try loading just the DEM alone by converting the raster to a matrix, I am able to view the DEM, but now I need to add the Lat and Long for locations from the Points.sp dataframe.

```
newelev <- as.matrix(newelev)
p <- plot_ly(z = ~newelev) %>% add_surface()
p
```

[image]

Any suggestions? I would ideally want points as small circles on the DEM for the region along with the DEM smoothed and stretched out.

*****UPDATE*****

Based on @wittich's elegant solution, I tried what he posted, but I am getting an image like the screenshot posted below.

[image]

Comment: Please either supply your data or at least some summaries. We have no idea what your `z` is, or your `Points.sp` data frame. This is clearly a problem arising from the format of your data and without that we can't help.

Comment: @Spacedman I have included the data. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: I don't think I can justify the time it would take me to work with a 777million cell raster - can you create a smaller raster, or give some code we can cut and paste to create a raster to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Spacedman  Made changes to include a smaller region of interest, along with sending you a link to the Data, if needed.

Comment: Any success @Spacedman ?

Comment: @VijayRamesh I updated my [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/247156/53268), is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here, that you have to translate your own coordinates to relative coordinates.

The way you use **`ploty`** you totally ignore the absolute coordinates. For plotting the DEM SRTM data you don't have the problem as it use the X, Y of the TIFF file.

Your `newelev.tif` example has the size of `624` x `1577` Pixel so your relative coordinates has to bee between

```
P1 <- c(0, 0)
P2 <- c(624, 1577)
```

In absolute values that would be:

```
P1.wgs84 <- c(8.1166702191853, 72.8750131881337)
P2.wgs84 <- c(21.2583375712263, 78.0750134593281)
```

I hope I could show you the problem. *If I find some time I will look for a programmable solution for you.*

---

#### Update

As promised here a way how you could do it... there is probably a better way, but anyway it works.

```
library("plotly")
library("rgdal")
library("raster")

# Point <- Points.sp[,c("Long", "Lat", "Elevation")] # to get ride of the first column
Point <- rbind(c(75.72130, 12.88470, 876.000),
                c(75.93559, 11.93745, 1494.523),
                c(75.82200, 12.38000, 1051.000),
                c(75.65570, 12.22010, 1176.000))
colnames(Point) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
rownames(Point) <- c(1:4)
head(Point)

Point.extent <- extent(Point[,1:2])
Point.extent <- Point.extent + 0.5 # grow extend 0.5 degree
Point.extent

setwd("/home/wittich/Downloads/GISStackExchange/")
elev <- raster("newelev.tif")
elev.new1 <- crop(elev, Point.extent) # use point extent
elev.new1

d <- dim(elev.new1) # get same dimension
point.raster <- raster(nrow=d[1], ncol=d[2], extent(elev.new1))
cells <- cellFromXY(point.raster, Point[,1:2])
point.raster[cells] <- Point[,3] # set height value to cells
crs(point.raster) <- crs(elev.new1) # copy crs just in case
point.raster

elev.new2 <- as.matrix(elev.new1)

# here comes the tricky part where it gets the row and col number by using the cell number and set it to a data frame
point.raster2 <- as.matrix(point.raster)
point.cell.value <- as.data.frame(point.raster, na.rm=TRUE )
point.df <- data.frame(rowColFromCell(point.raster, as.numeric(rownames(point.cell.value))), height=point.cell.value[,1])
head(point.df)

p <- plot_ly(z = elev.new2, type = "surface") %>% 
         add_trace(data = point.df, x = ~col, y = ~row, z = ~height, mode = "markers", type = "scatter3d", 
             marker = list(size = 5, color = "red", symbol = 104))
p
```

[image: output screenshot]

*Hope that was what you were looking for.*

---

#### Update II

I had also trouble to display the plot correctly, I thought that is a problem of my ubuntu R/rstudio setup. What helped was to open the plot in a Firefox browser window:

[image: open in new window]

Comment: Using the absolute coordinates would be also an option!

Comment: Thanks a ton @wittich. I shall play around with the code and try to get at a slightly different angle, smaller size of points as well as smoothen out the DEM. This is a great start!

Comment: Still having some trouble @wittich. Can I e-mail you my code so far? Perhaps you might know where I am going wrong. I am getting an error message, when I try setting height to cells :                                                            point.raster[cells] <- Point[,3] # set height value to cells

Comment: Check if `Point` is a matrix and has 3 columns, my using `is.matrix(Point)`. I used `rbind` to create the matrix. I created my code in a way that you can run it completely...  so just compare every step, and output of each variable. In your case it should work to create the matrix `Point` like this: `Point <- Points.sp[,c("Long", "Lat", "Elevation")]`. Try check for example if `head(Point[,3])` *(which is the 3rd column)* is similar to your data. And let me know if you need further help...

Comment: So, it is a matrix.. I think I sent you an invite to a chat where I have mentioned the other error. It looks like it works, but I am unable to see anything. There is a single dot in the background that is supposedly the DEM as well as points. Let me know if you got my chat invite.

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of what I am getting currently based on your solution. It's up as an update in my question.

Answer (score -2):

'z' must be a numeric matrix. Perhaps you need to set the matrix to number.

> > Convert your data frame dat2 to matrix with function as.matrix()?
> >     I got the example from [a stack over flow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279825/why-heatmap-2-in-r-failed-to-read-the-numeric-data-frame)

Comment: That aspect is taken care of when the elevation raster is loaded, as the DEM has a z value. Your answer does not help me with an output that has a DEM with points shown on the DEM.

Comment: the point was to set the value to numeric matrix.